# What's the difference between a Google Apps Script fetch POST request and a browser-initiated POST request?

Tags: google-apps-script, http-post, postman, urlfetch, http-delete

I'm using a third-party API and my POST request works as expected when I send from the API documentation "test" page in my browser, or from the Postman Windows native app.

I get error codes when I send the same request from Google Apps Script.  I am able to send/receive GET requests using GAS and I can also send/receive POST requests using GAS to other APIs.

This GAS GET request works correctly:

```
var options = {
  "headers" : {
    "Authorization" : "Bearer " + accessToken,
    "Accept": "application/json"
   }
 };
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

Headers:

```
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Language: en-US
Authorization: Bearer {token}
Content-Length: 638
Content-Type: application/json
DNT: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML
X-Forwarded-For: xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
X-Forwarded-Port: 443
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
```

This GAS POST request produces errors:

```
var options = {
 "headers" : {
   "Authorization" : "Bearer " + accessToken,
   "Accept": "application/json",
   "Content-Type": "application/json",
   "Accept-Language": "en-US"
 },
"method" : "post",
"payload" : JSON.stringify(this_payload)
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

The GAS POST request sends these headers:

```
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,br
Accept-Language:  en-US
Authorization: Bearer {token}
Connection:  close
Content-Length: 387
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Apps-Script)
```

This GAS POST request gives the error:

```
Response Code 500
code: infrastructure.common.SystemException
description:"System error, please re-try"
```

Is it possible that the API is simply not accepting connections from GAS?  The User-Agent lists Google-Apps-Script.  Or is it more likely that I have some parameter wrong?  I am able to get the parameters correct via two other platforms, so I think parameters are correct.

Comment: Capture the outgoing POST request and headers from postman and diff it against GAS?

Comment: As suggested by TheMaster, I used Postman to send the *working* request to httpbin.org.

I then used GAS to send the *non-working* request to httpbin.org.

Some of the headers were different, but the problem was not with headers.  It was a difference in a randomly generated parameter that apparently didn't meet the API specifications.

I am now able to get the same response in GAS as I do in any browser or plugin :-)